# Norms of linear functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I had to check continuity and find norms. I would be very grateful if somebody checked my answers.

**1)** $\mathbb{R}[X]\ni w \rightarrow w(2) \in \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R}[X]$ is equipped with norm $\|w\|:=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|w(t)|$

> This functional is not bounded and thus not continuous. We needed to find a constant C such that the inequality $$|w(2)|\le C \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|w(t)|$$holds. Consider a continuous function $f$ that is equal to $0$ on $[0,1]$ and then grows to some arbitrary large value $f(2)$. From the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, we can approximate this function with a polynomial as closely as we want. So basically, we can make left hand side of our inequality as high as we want, thus there is no universal constant $C$ such that this inequality holds for all polynomials $w$.

**2)** $c \ni (x_n) \rightarrow (\frac{1}{3^n}x_n) \in \ell^2$

> $$(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{3^n}x_n|^2)^{1/2}\le \sup_n|x_n| (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{3^n}|^2)^{1/2}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{8}} \|(x_n)\|$$

**3)** $c \ni (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \rightarrow (x_n - \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x_k) \in c_0$

> First, it is well defined as $(x_n - \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x_k)$ is in $c_0$.
>   $$\sup_n|x_n- \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x_k|\le 2 \sup_n|x_n|$$
>   Now take $x=(-1,1,1,1,\dots)$ and we have equality.

**4)** $c_{00} \ni (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nx_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}$

> We want to find C such that: $|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nx_{n+1}| \le C \cdot \sup_n |x_n|$
>   Consider a sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}=(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,\dots)$. Denote the number of the term where is the last $1$ with $k$. $\sup|y_n|=1$, but we can always replace $k+2$th zero with one and thus make left side bigger. So this functional is not bounded.

**5)** $C[-1,1] \ni f \rightarrow (\frac{n}{n^2+1} f((-1)^n)) \in \ell^{\infty}$ with $\int$ norm

> First, we notice that $\frac{n}{n^2+1} f((-1)^n) < \infty$ for all $n$.
>   We need to find a constant $C$ for which:
>   $$\sup_n |\frac{n}{n^2+1} f((-1)^n)| \le C \cdot \int_{-1}^1|f(t)|dt$$
>   Consider the function $$ g(x)  = \left\{ 
>    \begin{array}{l l}
>      0 & \quad x \in [-k,1] \\
>      -lx-lk & \quad x \in [-1,-k)
>    \end{array} \right.$$ where $$l>1$$
>   For a given k and l:
>   $$\sup_n |\frac{n}{n^2+1} f((-1)^n)|=\frac{1}{2} \cdot (l-lk) $$
>   Now notice that we can go with -k as close as we want to $-1$ and with $l$ as close as we want to $\infty$, thus making left hand side of our inequality arbitrary big and right hand side arbitrary small. Thus, there is no universal constant $C$.
>   Function g:
>   [image]

Comment: What are $c, c_{00}$?

Comment: $c$ - space of all convergent sequences, $c_0$ - space of all sequences convergent to 0, $c_{00}$ - space of all sequences eventually equal to 0

Comment: For **5)** I don't understand how $g$ is defined.

Comment: I added a picture... maybe it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with points $1$ to $4$.

For the last point, let's define for $k \in \mathbb N-\{1\}$

$$ g_k(x)  = \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{l l}
     -k^4x+k^2-k^4 & \quad x \in [-1,-1+\frac{1}{k^2}] \\
     0 & \quad x \in [-1+\frac{1}{k^2},1]
   \end{array} \right.$$
It looks a lot like your picture.

Note that $\forall k, \int_{-1}^{1}g_k=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\forall k, \;g_k(-1+\frac{1}{k^2})=0 $

For fixed $k$, $$\sup_n |\frac{n}{n^2+1} g_k((-1)^n)|=\frac{1}{2}k^2$$
and

$$\int_{-1}^1|g_k(t)|dt = \frac{1}{2}$$.

Since $$\frac{1}{2}k^2 \to \infty $$, the constant $C$ does not exist.

Comment: But my explanation in 1) is acceptable or do I need to make it more formal?

Comment: @luka5z I think it's just fine.